# A compute of Ricci Flow

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Let $g(0)=g_0$ and $Ric(g_0)=\lambda g_0,\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$,
the $Ric(g)$ is the Ricci curvature,$g$ is Riemannian metric.
How to show that :

The $g(t)=(1-2\lambda t)g_0$ is a solution of 
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}=-2Ric(g)
$$

Thanks for any detail answer or hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you multiply the metric by a factor,  the Ricci doesn't scale.  One way to see this is to look at its expression in the normal coordinates given [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature).

Comment: As an alternate, one can look at the usual expression for the Levi-Civita connection coefficients, from which it's clear that the connection is scale independent. The (3,1)-curvature tensor is formed just from the connection, so is also scale independent, and the Ricci is just a metric-independent trace of this, which shows Ricci is scale independent.